WPF - MaterialDesign for XAML
I have two separate solutions: Solution A defines a custom UserControl, as you can see here:
<TextBox BorderBrush="{Binding ValueFG, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
        Foreground="{Binding ValueFG, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
        md:HintAssist.HelperText="{Binding ValueHT, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
        md:TextFieldAssist.LeadingIcon="{Binding ValueIcon, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
        Text="{Binding ValueInput, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        Width="{Binding ValueWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>

public string ValueIcon
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(ValueIconProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ValueIconProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueIconProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(ValueIcon),
        typeof(string),
        typeof(TxtInput),
        new PropertyMetadata("HumanGreeting"));

The only problem that I have, is that the corresponding icon from MaterialDesign does not get displayed.
Within Solution B, I added the namespace and the reference to Solution A. Then I added this custom Usercontrol and tried to set the icon fia it's corresponding Binding property.
 <uc:TxtInput KeyText="Developer Name" 
              DockPanelMargin="{Binding NameMargin}"
              ValueFG="{Binding NameFG}" 
              ValueHT="{Binding NameHT}"
              ValueInput="{Binding Name}"
              ValueIcon="HumanGreetingVariant"
              Style="{StaticResource TxtInputLocal}"/>

Unfortunately, the icon does not get added at all. I also added a second one, with no explicit Icon in order to let the default-icon apply -> I still got no icon displayed.

Within another project I already worked with those icons. I always set them as a string and it worked as expected.
Also if I create this UserControl within the same solution, it works as expected.

I could figure it out by myself:
Within the Xaml, I had to add the following attribute:
md:TextFieldAssist.HasLeadingIcon="True"

And within the Code-Behind, I had to change the Propery to PackIconKind
public PackIconKind ValueIcon
{
    get { return (PackIconKind)GetValue(ValueIconProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ValueIconProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueIconProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(ValueIcon),
        typeof(PackIconKind),
        typeof(TxtInput),
        new PropertyMetadata(PackIconKind.HumanGreeting));

